# Why are people so eager to grab Shisui's eyes even though it activates rarely?

Tags: naruto

Shisui's Mangekyou Sharingan casts the mind-control genjutsu, Kotoamatsukami, but it activates only once in a decade. Why are people so eager to grab his eyes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Several big spoilers ahead.**

Three people have been showed to be eager to grab Shisui's eye, namely Danzo, Tobi and Kabuto. Besides that, they have one other thing in common:

> They all have access to Senju Hashirama's cells, which significantly reduces the reactivation time of Shisui's eye. Hence, these people could put it to practical use without the undesirable restriction.
>
>  **Danzo**'s case actually shows this reduction of the reactivation time. He had stolen Shisui's right eye shortly before the Uchiha incident, and had Orochimaru implant Hashirama's cells into his body. He was able to activate Shisui's eye twice in a day, first during the five Kage meeting and later towards the end of his battle with Sasuke.
>
>  **Tobi** is later revealed to be Uchiha Obito. The right half of his body, destroyed during the Kannabi bridge battle, was repaired/replaced by Madara with Hashirama's cells.
>
>  **Kabuto** had access to Hashirama's cells due to both working under Orochimaru previously and through Yamato whom he had captured during the fourth shinobi world war. Shisui's left eye emerges during the war from Naruto's mouth due to Itachi's setup. Kabuto also hears Itachi talk about the use of Hashirama's cells to reduce Kotoamatsukami's reactivation time. He hoped to grab it for his own use.

Comment: I wonder how did Sishui himself used it. Not very useful eyes that only activate once in a decade, or perhaps because they were naturally his they didn't take as long? I don't know.

Comment: I think it is the second. Given that he died at the age of less than 20, if the restriction applied to him, he would have used each eye once. That is hardly enough to give his eyes their legendary status.

Comment: Wow nice attention to detail and good explanation. :)